# Move ghost toward player in maze if player is nearby?

Tags: c++, maze

I think this is a fairly easy thing to implement but I just want the ghost to begin moving one space at a time toward the player, if the player is within 5 spaces of the ghost. In my if statement in move_to_x_y is where the change should be added. How can I do the if statement to move depending on where the player is?

Here is the function checking to see if the ghost is within five spaces:

```
bool Game::nearby (Ghost & ghost) const
{
if (abs(m_player->get_x() - ghost.get_x()) < 5)
    return true;
if (abs(m_player->get_y() - ghost.get_y()) < 5)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

Then here is the ghost's move function, he usually just moves in a random direction, which is the else case for when the player is not within five spaces:

```
void Ghost::move (Game & game) {
Floor *     floor;
int         r;
bool        moved = false;

floor = game.get_curr_floor();
do
{
    if (game.nearby(*this))
        r = //WHAT TO ADD HERE???
    else {
    r = rand() % 4;
    switch (r)
    {
    case 0:
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 1, 0);
        break;
    case 1:
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, -1);
        break;
    case 2:
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y(game, *this, -1, 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        moved = floor->move_to_x_y(game, *this, 0, 1);
        break;
    }
    }
}
while (! moved);
}
```

So depending on where the player is, either move up, down, left or right, toward them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: Edited it. Sorry it wasn't clear. "How can I do the if statement to move depending on where player is?"

Comment: Also, why is there a loop?  Oh, the `rand()`.  Got it.  I would probably not do that.  Give it a fallthrough so if it tries to move right and fails, it then tries down, then left, then up.

Comment: Oh ok. Well it is supposed to be able to move through walls so I'm not too worried about the rand() since the ghost can move anywhere on the map.

Comment: That's a pretty bad distance test, btw. You should probably take both x and y distance into account (either add them, or take Euclidean distance). Otherwise, the ghost can be on the opposite side of the screen, but still be considered "nearby" if it is lined up either horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Well, the same issue seems to be coming up with these answers, once the ghost hits an edge, the game freezes. Which didn't happen before the ghost could move toward the player (AI was implemented).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns whether or not the player is nearby, but gives no information as to which direction the player is in. Change the return value from a bool to an int, or something to indicate the direction. For example:

```
int Game::nearby (Ghost & ghost) const
{
if (ghost.get_x() - m_player->get_x() < 5 && ghost.get_x() - m_player->get_x() > 0)
    return 2;
if (m_player->get_x() - ghost.get_x() < 5 && m_player->get_x() - ghost.get_x() > 0)
    return 0;
if (ghost.get_y() - m_player->get_y() < 5 && ghost.get_y() - m_player->get_y() > 0)
    return 3;
if (m_player->get_y() - ghost.get_y() < 5 && m_player->get_y() - ghost.get_y() > 0)
    return 1;
return -1;
}
```

This will return the number that already corresponds to the direction you want him to move in your switch statement. So all you have to do in your move function is set r to the int "nearby" returns, and if it returns -1, set it to a random direction as before.

```
r = game.nearby(*this);
if (r == -1)
    r = rand() % 4;

switch (r) .... etc
```

Comment: Ahh okay, is this statement `if (r == -1)` where the ghost moves toward the player? This still doesn't seem to have a "then" element, like if == -1, move toward the player, you just have it doing a random movement don't you?

Comment: No, the ghost moves to the player using your switch statement. The only difference is what 'r' gets set to. If the player is within range of the ghost, r gets set to the number it needs to be to make the right case in your switch statement. But if the player is out of range, r will be set to -1, and will then be set to a random number.

Comment: Oh okay, is there any reason why it is saying -> has not pointer type 'Ghost' even though we pass in ghost as a reference? Not sure why that comes up.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I had accidentally written ghost->get_x() and m_player.get_x() instead of the other way around. It should be fixed now.

Comment: With this method, if the player is two up and one to the right, but there's a wall directly above the ghost, the game will freeze. More advice needed.

Comment: There seems to be an issue where the ghost just moves left everytime and the player can't move because the ghost hits the left edge of the map. Does this `return -1;` need to be adjusted? Doesn't it return -1 every time so the ghost will always move left?

Comment: You should not be using magic numbers. Either return vector, or use enums for direction,

Comment: @aishere:  The enumerations in this code don't match your question, you'll need to adjust them.  Note that this code uses `4` for moving up, and yours don't handle `4` at all.  Also this code assumes `x` and `y` are `unsigned`,  If they're not, this code won't quite work as is

Comment: @aishere As Mooing Duck pointed out, the return values were a little bit off. I just edited them, so they should be the proper values now.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: OP mentioned in the comments on his original question that the ghost can move through walls.

Comment: Are the third and forth if statement supposed to be nested? You have open { after the first and second case but never closed so I'm a bit confused what you were going for.

Comment: No, they're not. Those brackets shouldn't be there. Sorry, I'm new to posting here and not used to writing code in this format!

Comment: this fuction also has a bias making the ghost look a little stupid. it favors moves in x direction even if the gain in y direction would be bigger. not in absolute nuber of moves but for human understanding. this bias could also disable the ghost cornering of the player.

Comment: I think the `if (r == -1)` means that the ghost will get stuck eventually, this is way the game freezes once the ghost the edge of the maze on either side...which happens every time I've run it.

Comment: while in pricipal this solution is correct it supports a misinterpretation of the design. the Game::nearby is not intended to imperatively move the ghost. It is meant to provide the ghost with information about the players position. It is up to the ghosts strategy how to use this information. so nearby should return a direction in degrees, compass points or as distance vector. hte ghost then may decide to approach the player or sit and duck.

Comment: if (r == -1) r = rand() % 4; Just selects a random number, like you were doing before. You should also add checks to make sure the ghost is not at the edge of the map, and if it is, don't allow it to move over the edge.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably do something like this:

```
if (game.nearby(*this))
{
    int x = player_position_x - ghost_position_x;
    int y = player_position_y - ghost_position_y;

    if (abs(x) > abs(y))
    {
        assert(x != 0);
        x = x / abs(x);
        y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(y != 0);
        x = 0;
        y = y / abs(y);
    }

    floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, x, y);
    moved = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd change the `bool Game::nearby` to return a compass point if the player is nearby.

---

EDIT: a comment to misunderstanding of the design

`Game::nearby()` is not intended to imperatively move the ghost. It is meant to provide the ghost with information about the players position. It is up to the ghosts strategy how to use this information. So nearby should return a direction in degrees, compass points or as distance vector. The ghost then may decide to approach the player or sit and duck. In a pacman game all 4 monsters could use this function but apply different strategies.

Comment: With this method, if the player is two up and one to the right, but there's a wall directly above the ghost, the game will freeze.  More advice needed.

Comment: @moo: OP said ghost will move through walls. but that's not the point. the ghost gets the correct information. he then decides to what to do with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts. First, try to move closer to the player

```
void Ghost::move (Game & game) {
    Floor *     floor game.get_curr_floor();
    bool        moved = false;

    if (game.nearby(*this)) {
        //try to move closer in x direction
        if (game.get_player()->get_x() > ghost.get_x())
            moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 1, 0);
        else if (ghost.get_x() > game.get_player()->get_x())
            moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, -1, 0);
        //if we haven't moved, try to move closer in y direction
        if (!moved && game.get_player()->get_y() > ghost.get_y())
            moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, 1);
        else if (!moved && ghost.get_y() > game.get_player()->get_y())
            moved = floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, -1);
    }
```

If that fails or the player is too far away, try to move randomly.  If a random direction fails, try the next direction in order.  This means we will try at most four directions, with no chance of an infinite loop.  This has a slight bias at three way intersections, but that's probably not noticeable.  It also has the side effect that if the ghost literally cannot move, the game doesn't freeze.

```
    //if not moved closer, move randomly
    if (!moved) {
        int r = rand() % 4; //pick random direction
        switch(r) {
        case 0: 
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 1, 0))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
        case 1: 
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, -1, 0))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
        case 2: 
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, 1))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
        case 3: 
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, -1))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
        default: 
            //if it was case 3, need to try all other directions still
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 1, 0))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
            if(floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, -1, 0))
                break; //if it failed, try the next one
            floor->move_to_x_y (game, *this, 0, 1);
            //at this point, all directions have been tried. We're done.
        }//switch             
    } //if
}
```

Comments point out there's a bug in the `nearby` function, that it considers anything on the same x axis to be "close".

Comment: So you are suggesting to leave nearby() exactly as I had it? Then implement everything you listed into the move function? Then pass in m_player?

Comment: first: ghost has no player member which is good design. second the bias is a catastropy as the gost would always act predictable if trying to leave the map.

Comment: @aishere: Oh, I hadn't noticed they were members of different classes.  You could just use `game.getPlayer()` or something.

Comment: @stefan: A catastrophe?  It only affects three-way-intersections and corners.  In "hallways" and four-way-intersections, it's perfectly random.  The corners are the worst case, and even then he moves the "rare" direction 25% of the time.

Comment: @moo: if reaching the edge of the map and the fallthrough is 'follow edge right' there is a 1/4 chance to leve the edge and 3/4 chance to stick to it.

Comment: This looks good, I think I'll implement @Tabula Rusa's answer, but this is also a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: @stefan: I assumed `move_to_x_y` would return `false` if the move was invalid, like off the edge of the map.  The bias is not as simple as "turn right": In which case: on the right edge he moves left 50%. On the left edge he moves down 50%. On the top edge he moves right 50%, and on the bottom he moves up 50%.  Assuming all other movement options are available.

Comment: @moo: we leave aout corners: if `case 0:` or `case 2:`fails the ghost will **always bounce**. that is 50% leave the edge and 25% for a turn to either side. if `case 1:` or `case 3:`fails the ghost will always stick to that edge and **never bounce**. that is 25% for leaving the edge, 50% for following the edge in the preferred direction and 25% for the other turn.

Comment: to maintain the ghost behaviour the relative probability between directions shall not be changed. the invalid option shall be removed the remaining probabilities scaled to sum up to 100% again. in our case on an edge the probability for the remaining three directions shall be 33%. in a corner it shall be 50% for both remaining directions. that behaviour you can achieve by either do that explicitely or by lazily repeating to move randomly until you hit a valid option like in the OPs posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

For each ghost for every update:

1. Attempt to acquire player position.
2. If player position cannot be acquired (blocked by the wall), do nothing for this ghost in this update (`return`/`continue`)
3. Measure distance to player.
4. If distance is higher than maximum "awareness range", do nothing for this ghost in this update (`return`/`continue`)
5. Move in direction of player.

Also, do not use "magic numbers" (`case 0:`) in your code. Use either enums or constants.

So, get rid of "nearby" and replace it with function that returns player position.